# Sending a string from an app to a server

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, android-studio

I have been working on an app which will send a string to a database on my server, however for some reason no data is received. Maybe you could point me in the right direction, I have been searching all over the net but can't find the reason why it's not working.

My android code:

```
    public class HttpURLConnectionHandler
    {
    protected String urlG = "http://example.com/";
    public String sendText(String text)
    {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlG+"phpcode.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());

            wr.writeBytes("mydata:"+text);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){ return "error";}
    }

}
```

My code in php:

```
<?php
$servername = "here is my server";
$username = "my username";
$password = "my pass";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$image = $_POST['image'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO photos (image)
VALUES ('{$image}')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The way I call my class is:

```
HttpURLConnectionHandler handler= new HttpURLConnectionHandler();
String response = handler.sendText("this is a text");
```

Comment: Json would be a better option in terms of server to client communication

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but firstly your android code and php code don't match, both of them are written for different purposes. Secondly try some libraries like volley or okhttp for Network requests.

Comment: Main purpose of the app is to send a string to a database on my server, I'm quite new to this, that's why I'm struggling a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I let you look around [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

You trying to get value of POST variable **image** in your PHP, but you sending variable **mydata**.

Comment: so if I want to send a string to my databse what instead of POST should I be using?

Comment: $image = $_POST['mydata']; I never write code for android, but I think that your code never sends "image" variable to POST. You can see all values of POST request by adding something like: var_dump($_POST); to your PHP code.